# How to migrate from Android 5.1 to iPhone 8?

Tags: iphone, migration, android

Is it possible and how to move all info, contacts, images, photos, mp4 files from android 5.1 to iPhone?

Comment: This might not be a duplicate(of questions that I came across) as version is important here.

Comment: The official app from Apple: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apple.movetoios

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, **yes**.

I imagine there is a minimum OS version on both Android and iOS but there is an officially supported (by Apple) method which they detail [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201196). There is also an app "Move to iOS", that goes on the Android phone [available in Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apple.movetoios).